# Yodlee: User account is locked

Tags: yodlee

I got below error message while connecting yodlee.
"**The account for user private-xxxxxxxx is locked**". It's already worked properly in past days. But today we got this problem while connecting yodlee via API.

Can you please address how to unlock my account or how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to contact Yodlee's customer care and get your account unlocked.